# How to read a text file into a string and print out index 1 for link 2 info?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a test file contains multiple lines for names.

For example:

```
Andy
Kevin
Lisa
Mike
```

I tried to use the below code to read them into a string. And print second line names by using index.

```
with open("....names.txt", 'r') as f:
names = f.read().replace('\n ', "")
print(names[1])
```

but when I do this, the index1 print out is n instead of second link info.
What I should change to make it the same as the code below:

```
names = ["Andy", "Kevin", "Lisa", "Mike"]
print(names[1])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Python starts counting from 0 instead of 1. so index 0 is actually the first item in a list, and index 1 is the second one. I like to remember it by thinking that the index represents how many items in the list come before that specific item. (nothing before the first item, so index 0)

Comment: Have you tried examining the value of `names` in the first snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = []
with open("....names.txt", 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    names.append(line.strip())
    
print(names[1])
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
with open("....names.txt", 'r') as f:
  names = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use .split(), this chops up a string, and puts its pieces into an array:

```
nameString = "Andy Kevin Lisa Mike"
nameArray = nameString.split(" ")
```